# should I create workspace for each java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, workspace

What should be the standard practice for workspace usage?

- create different workspaces for different projects,
- create one workspace for all projects
- categorize projects and create workspace accordingly (like java projects, J2EE projects, android projects).

Also in case we import a project into eclipse what workspace should I select ideally?

This seems to be a basic thing but I want clarity on the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definite answer to this as it's just a workflow preference. However the way that I handle this is that if I have on big thing I am working on which consists of multiple projects, I keep that all in one workspace, this can be necessary if you build with eclipse (rather than Maven), and they are dependencies for each other. If they are entirely separate things, then they have their own.

But no one can give you a 'correct' answer, as it is just what suits you. If you have too many things open at once in Eclipse can make it a little slow but if it is a project you are working on by yourself it is unlikely to be that big of an issue.

Comment: thanks @william very helpful answer, what about importing projects, while I am imprting maven based project in eclipse should I give the workspace location same as projects(where project is cloned through VCS like git)?

Comment: Personally mine is organize so that the parent directory of all my projects is my workspace, and I just import them all as separate projects. Git works fine with this set up, I'm not entirely sure what the question is

Answer (score 2):

If you have depending projects you have to use one workspace. If this is not the case do whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Is that entirely true? A lot of people use eclipse and compile from within eclipse using Maven which doesn't have this issue (like myself)

Comment: If maven resolves your dependencies that's fine (and a good idea IMHO). Ohters prefer to work with dependant Eclipse projects. In this case you must have them in the same workspace.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on you. You can do all project in single workspace but its better if you create different workspase for different technology.

For example :

J2EE - Create new workspase

Android -- Create new workspace

GWT -- Create new workspace

Answer (score 2):

To manage project properly you should have to create workspace with the same name of the project and import all module or dependencies in that workspace itself. But there is no hard and fast rule, its totally depends on you how you want to manage it.

Comment: okay,but while importing external projects, should workspace be the same as of that projects location?

Comment: If your project going to depend on that external project (which you are going to import) import it in the same workspace otherwise create new workspace take a reference and delete.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one workspace for one set of projects like androidworkspace, workspace etc. Any way you are giving project names under each workspace, so this is what we generally follow.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely subjective, but the way I see it, it's comparable to packages and their respective classes.  Do you create a package for every class?  No, generally you put classes that perform a similar task or work together in the same package.  In most cases you're not doing so in order to access a class's protected methods, but rather for organization.

Likewise projects are the macro-level classes, with each one performing a specific role.  The workspace for me is the "package" of the projects, usually with each project having a dependency or is depended upon by another project in the same workspace.

That said, I have separate workspaces using the same projects, because while the overall scope of the projects change, some projects are depended on by several others (unlike packages of course).  For me a workspace corresponds to a collective group of projects for a single application or scope.